# IndexController not found in ZendFramework

Tags: apache, .htaccess, zend-framework, virtualhost

I created a new ZendFramework project with two controllers Index and Admin.

Also I created virtual host for this site. Here is my site./etc/apache2/sites-enebled/site.home.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
DocumentRoot /home/user/server/site/public/
ServerName site.home
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/server/site/public/>
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory></VirtualHost>
```

Here is my ~/server/site/public/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Everything looks fine, because in general it is a copy from my another projects on the same server, but(!) I have the next server behaviour:

```
http://site.home - OK (code 200)
http://site.home/index or http://site.home/index/index - page not found (code 404 from Apache)
http://site.home/Index (with capital I) - OK (code 200)
http://site.home/admin or http://site.home/admin/index - OK (code 200)
```

So problem is only when I call "index" controller. How to fix it?

**UPDATE**
I found workaround. I create an "index" folder in /public and http://site.home/index works fine!
But I think it is not a solution...

Comment: Check if class name of your IndexController is correct.

Comment: Yes, it was created automatically

Comment: @lubart created atomatically how, zf tool?

Comment: Enable errors and then show us the error: add `resources.frontcontroller.params.displayExceptions = 1` and `phpSettings.display_errors = 1` to you ini configs

Comment: thank you for reply. project was create by NetBeans through zf tool. And I obtained error from server (404 Not Found), not from zf. But @Tim Fountain already provide me an good advise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `MultiViews` option from your vhost and then I think it should work fine. The `<Directory /> ... </Directory>` section is unnecessary and could also be removed.